# Update of Table when I don't have the key value

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, dto

I am developing a .net core api using entity framework.  I have done development for a while but am new to entity framework.  In addition I am attempting to implement using DTO objects to restrict and reduce the amount of information available.  My problem is this.  If I do not pass my unique id from the DB back to the end user how can I perform an update against that object?

For example I have a class that has

ID, FirstName, LastName, Age

My DTO back to the end user is:

FirstName, LastName, Age

How can I implement Update and Delete without the ID?

I know this is probably a dumb question and I am missing the obvious so please be gentle.  I have looked for the answer but every time I search I just keep finding questions about tables that don't have a primary key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't update a record without using Id or another primary key.  For example to update the user you need to find an existed user record, update some or all properties and save. The only way to find the user without using Id would be

```
var existedUser = Context.Set<User>().Where(u=> u.FirstName==dto.FirstName 
&& u.LastName==dto.LastName  
&& u.Age==dto.Age).FirstOrDefault();
```

but since you have to update user properties it means FirstName or LastName or Age or all of them are changed in your Dto already, so you can't  use them to find a user record to update.

You can use this code to find a user to delete, but it is not the best idea too, since can be a differet user with the same name and age.

Comment: That makes sense.  So why is it that all the experts talk about Leaky Keys?  How are they performing updates if they do not return the key as part of their DTO object?  Sorry for so many follow-ups I am just trying to get this right.  By the way thanks for the help Serge.

Comment: But what is the problem to include Id in your Dto? You are getting all the properties from db  why it is not included Id?

Comment: It is my understanding that it is bad practice to send system information back to the end user.  It waste bandwidth as well as compromises your system.  One example I got from someone is that if you send the Key and it is an int value that a hacker can then determine the number of records in your table.  I don't believe that to be true because it is my experience that with int keys values are always skipped.  But anyway I am just trying to build something more soundly and am confused by how at this point.

Comment: @pachyderm94 Even security tokens are send this way. Everybody  uses Id. I have never seen a project where it was not used.  You are the first.  The only way to keep information private is to use https protocol. Nothing else is working.

Comment: @pachyderm94 And how you get First,last names and so on?  I can only guess tha tyou sent a GET request with ID , why you don't use it now?

Comment: Please understand that I agree with you.  I can't figure out how to not use the keys.  I am new to using DTO objects.  In the past I have always just passed base objects back and fourth.  This application will be audited so I need to make sure I have crossed my eyes and dotted my T's.  I will say that your comment about using SSL while correct seems to ignore the fact that for many companies a lot of hacking occurs by nosy employees who actually have access to use a system but not necessarily access to the DB.